# What is wrong in my proof related to Lebesgue measure.

Tags: real-analysis

I am asked to show that Lebesgue measure is translation invariant.
Proof :-

Given that E is a measurable subset of $\mathtt R^d$ , then by definition of measurable set there exists an open set O containing E such that $m(O-E) \lt \epsilon$.
Now the translation set $E_h$ ={ x+h / x  is  in E}.
Then as O is an open set $O_h$ is also open and $E_h \subset O_h$ with the property that $m($O_h-E_h$) = m(O-E) \lt \epsilon$.
Hence $E_h$ is measurable subset of $R^d$.

Are all my steps correct??

Comment: As I am a P.G student , I am asked this to prove in short. A long proof is available with me. Need valid proof.

Comment: You haven't shown that $m(E) = m(E_h)$.

Comment: Yes you are right. What steps should I do to show this

Comment: @Kavita that depends on how your measure is defined on open sets.

Comment: That definition I have mentioned in my proof